# How to deal with a rules related lock_wait that occurs after a cache clear and results in slow transactions

Tags: 7, performance

This application needs to run cron every 15 minutes which results in a `cache_clear_all`.  Whenever this happens hundreds, sometimes thousands, of db_log entries happen for "Cache rebuild lock hit: rules_event_whitelist" which results in a lot of slow transactions: [image: New Relic screen shot].

I'm setting up jMeter tests for a development environment so that I can reproduce and test fixes, but my question is: Is there a best practice fix for this?  I discovered that the memcache locking mechanism is not being used - maybe that would help? ( I can't test this in a production environment and a similar development environment hasn't been given to me yet).

Update: I'm able to reproduce this in a smaller dev environment.  Updating to the memcache locking and stampede protection does not solve the issue.

Comment: Are you using something for cron  management?

Comment: I though about elysia but as I understand it, a cron run calls cache_clear_all so although I may be able to get performance improvements out of it, I don't think it will address this problem.

Comment: Possibly related: https://www.drupal.org/node/2650886